# Auto lock cells when filled in excel

Tags: excel, vba

I know how to lock cells

```
E.g.
CTRL+1 lock set password
```

What I want is to have all cells accessible UNTIL data is entered then it becomes uneditable to the user.
Please advise.

Comment: I'm afraid for this you'll need VBA and play with the Worksheet events.

Comment: I cannot recommend this approach. This way the user cannot correct the data if he made a mistake. I recommend to protect all cells containing data using the [Workbook.BeforeSave event](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.workbook.beforesave). So the user can edit the cells where he entered data until he saves the workbook. Then all data cells get locked (and he cannot edit them anymore).

Comment: Other complications include it being easy for the user to unprotect the sheet and edit cells... unless you specify the password in the code which then you also need to protect... of course you can protect the code but it can be broken because VBA does not aim to be all that secure, and so on. Depending on your needs maybe forms would be a better effort investment?